# Why does an NGXS URL-Selector in an Angular Service fires only once?

Tags: angular, redux, ngxs

We are building an application with a few different NgModules (part of them lazy-loaded) and use NGXS for state management (with [NgxsRouterPluginModule with a Custom Serializer](https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/router#custom-router-state-serializer)). For building the Navigation bar, I wanted to create a service that maps the URL to the active section, so that an `active` CSS class can be added to the correct element.

Since we use NGXS, I want to implement it with Selectors and Actions:

1. Subscribe to URL changes in `SectionIdService` with `@Select()`
2. Dispatch Action `Core.SetSectionId` in this Service
3. Patch state in `core.state.ts` with `{ sectionId: action.sectionId }`
4. Subscribe to sectionId changes in Navigation Component with `@Select()`

However, I noticed that `sectionId` in the Navigation Component is always undefined. The Redux Devtools Plugin in Chrome shows that the Action `Set Section ID` is only triggered once - at the very beginning, right after `@@INIT`. After that, even when a `Router Navigation` Action is dispatched, the subscription to `state.router.state.url` doesn't fire:

[image: Redux Devtools: Set Section ID doesn't fire after RouterNavigation event]

For debugging, I included the following code in `ArticlePageComponent` (Module `Articles`, lazy loaded) and in `NavigationComponent` (Module `Core`, imported in `AppModule`):

```
@Select(state => state.router.state.url) url$: Observable<string>;
  
constructor(private store: Store) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.url$.subscribe(url => console.log("**** URL **** : " + url));
}
```

And the result was confusing: the log in `NavigationComponent` was *not* triggered with the correct URL.

[image]

Since I have a working Subscription `@Select(state => state.router.state.params.slug) slug$: Observable<string>;` in another component, I know that subscribing to Router events work. But here, it doesn't.

Could this have something to do with timing? Shouldn't the Subscription in the SectionId-Service or the NavigationComponent fire any time the URL changes? What am I doing wrong here?

**Complete code**:

navigation.component.ts (Module Core)

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Select(state => state.core.navigation) navigation$: Observable<Navigation>;
  @Select(state => state.core.sectionId) sectionId$: Observable<string>;
  
  constructor(private store: Store) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(Core.FetchNavigation);
  }
}
```

navigation.component.html

```
<nav *ngIf="navigation$ | async as navigation" role="navigation" class="w-100">
  <ul class="ye-nav">
    <li *ngFor="let navigationItem of navigation.navigation"
      [ngClass]="{'has-flyout': navigationItem.links, 'active': navigationItem.id === (sectionId$ | async)}">
      <a class="nav-link" [href]="navigationItem.link">
        <span class="nav-btn">{{navigationItem.name}}</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="flyout"
        [ngClass]="{'multicolumn-flyout': navigationItem.multicolumn}"
        *ngIf="navigationItem.links">
        <li *ngIf="navigationItem.all_link" class="flyout-title">
          <a [href]="navigationItem.link">{{navigationItem.all_link}}</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngFor="let subNavigationItem of navigationItem.links">
          <a class="nav-link" [href]="subNavigationItem.link">{{subNavigationItem.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

section-id.service.ts (Module Core)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SectionIdService implements OnDestroy {

  @Select(state => state.router.state.url) url$: Observable<string>;
  private destroy: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  private urlPrefixToSectionIdMap = [
    { urlPrefix: '/video-kategorien', sectionId: 'videos' },
    { urlPrefix: '/video-kategorie', sectionId: 'videos' },
    { urlPrefix: '/programme', sectionId: 'programs' },
    { urlPrefix: '/yogalehrer', sectionId: 'teachers' },
    { urlPrefix: '/yogastile', sectionId: 'styles' },
    { urlPrefix: '/events', sectionId: 'events' },
    { urlPrefix: '/artikel/so-gehts', sectionId: 'tutorials' },
    { urlPrefix: '/so-gehts', sectionId: 'tutorials' },
    { urlPrefix: '/magazin', sectionId: 'blogs' },
    { urlPrefix: '/artikel', sectionId: 'blogs' }
  ];

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.url$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(url => {  // <-- this does not work as expected
      console.log('URL: ' + url);
      if (url === undefined) {
        this.store.dispatch(new Core.SetSectionId(undefined));
      } else if (url === '') {
        this.store.dispatch(new Core.SetSectionId('root'));
        console.log('SectionID: root');
      } else {
        const element = this.urlPrefixToSectionIdMap.find(el => url.startsWith(el.urlPrefix));
        this.store.dispatch(new Core.SetSectionId(element?.sectionId));
        console.log('SectionID: ' + element?.sectionId);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy.next(true);
    this.destroy.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

core.state.ts

```
export interface CoreStateModel {
  navigation: Navigation;
  sectionId: string;
}

@State<CoreStateModel>({
  name: 'core',
  defaults: {
    navigation: undefined,
    sectionId: 'root'
  }
})
@Injectable()
export class CoreState {
  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService,
              private sectionIdService: SectionIdService) {}

  @Action(Core.FetchNavigation)
  fetchNavigation(ctx: StateContext<CoreStateModel>, _) {
    return this.navigationService.getNavigation().pipe(
      tap(navigation => ctx.patchState({ navigation }))
    );
  }

  @Action(Core.SetSectionId)
  setSectionId(ctx: StateContext<CoreStateModel>, action: Core.SetSectionId) {
    ctx.patchState({ sectionId: action.sectionId });
  }
}
```

core.actions.ts

```
export namespace Core {
  export class FetchNavigation {
    static readonly type = '[Core] Fetch navigation';
  }

  export class SetSectionId {
    static readonly type = '[Core] Set Section ID';
    constructor(public sectionId: string) {}
  }
}
```

core.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AnnouncementComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HeaderSearchComponent,
    HeaderUserMenuComponent,
    MobileNavigationComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    ScrollToTopComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forFeature([CoreState]),
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AnnouncementComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MobileNavigationComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    ScrollToTopComponent
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot([], { developmentMode: !environment.production }),
    NgxsRouterPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot({ disabled: environment.production }),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot({ disabled: environment.production }),
    Angulartics2Module.forRoot(),
    NgbModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: AppRoutingSerializer }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.serializer.ts

```
export class AppRoutingSerializer implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateParams> {
  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateParams {
    const {
      url,
      root: { queryParams }
    } = routerState;

    let { root: route } = routerState;
    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
    }

    const { params } = route;

    return { url, params, queryParams };
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks from the redux output that maybe that subscribe call that fails is happening before the router state is loaded by NGXS? Can you check if @Select(state => state.router.state.url )fails, does just selecting state => state.router returning anything?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you :)